# Facebook connect login switch back to user breaks out of div

Tags: php, css, facebook

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for hours but I cannot figure it out.  Usually I can find my answer by searching StackOverFlow but this time I'm truly stumped.

The "Login with Facebook" button works perfectly fine when logged in as a FB User.  But when logged in as a FB Page, it gives the "switch back to xxxxx user to use this plugin", which is perfectly normal.  However the blank/white part of this message breaks out of the div and covers up the other contents of my page!

The code is as follows:

```
<div id="LoginButton" style="margin-top:20px;width:130px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<?
if(!$fbuser) //Only show login button if user is not Logged In to FB
{
  echo '<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="javascript:CallAfterLogin();" size="small" scope="email">Login w/ Facebook</div><div class="clear"></div>';
}
else
{
   //process user as a FB user
} 
?>
</div>
```

I've tried:

- clearing the div, which doesn't seem to matter
- testing with just plain text inside fb-login-button, which parent div
  LoginButton seems to contain fine
- replacing fb-login-button code with rendered code from Facebook JS
  API, but then the button is not clickable anymore

You can see the problem present if you surf the website http://www.dealshongkong.com as a FB page (you can see it happen on the left hand side of the page).

I've attached a pic here of what I see when logged in as FB Page (the problem):
http://www.dealshongkong.com/temp/stackoverflowproblem.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the very same problem. I found no other way arround than to use a custom Facebook Login Button. I just built a PNG file and added some Facebook JavaScript API call.

```
<div id="FaceBookLoginButton" onclick="FB.login(function(response) { }, 
{scope: \'email\'});" 
style="background-image:url(/buttons/my_own_facebook_login_button.png);" 
/>
<span>Log in</span>
</div>
```

It works fine for the login button. But in case you want to use other social plug-ins (Like-Button, Like-Box, Send-Button, ...) you will experience the same problem again.